# NSCharacterSet.characterIsMember() with Swift's Character type

Tags: swift

Imagine you've got an instance of Swift's `Character` type, and you want to determine whether it's a member of an `NSCharacterSet`. `NSCharacterSet`'s `characterIsMember` method takes a `unichar`, so we need to get from `Character` to `unichar`.

The only solution I could come up with is the following, where `c` is my `Character`:

```
let u: unichar = ("\(c)" as NSString).characterAtIndex(0)
if characterSet.characterIsMember(u) {
    dude.abide()
}
```

I looked at `Character` but nothing leapt out at me as a way to get from it to `unichar`. This may be because `Character` is more general than `unichar`, so a direct conversion wouldn't be safe, but I'm only guessing.

If I were iterating a whole string, I'd do something like this:

```
let s = myString as NSString
for i in 0..<countElements(myString) {
    let u = s.characterAtIndex(i)
    if characterSet.characterIsMember(u) {
        dude.abide()
    }
}
```

(Warning: The above is pseudocode and has never been run by anyone ever.) But this is not really what I'm asking.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My understanding is that `unichar` is a typealias for `UInt16`. A `unichar` is just a number.

I think that the problem that you are facing is that a `Character` in Swift can be composed of more than one unicode "characters". Thus, it cannot be converted to a single `unichar` value because it may be composed of two unichars. You can decompose a `Character` into its individual `unichar` values by casting it to a string and using the `utf16` property, like this:

```
let c: Character = "a"
let s = String(c)
var codeUnits = [unichar]()
for codeUnit in s.utf16 {
    codeUnits.append(codeUnit)
}
```

This will produce an array - `codeUnits` - of `unichar` values.

EDIT: Initial code had `for codeUnit in s` when it should have been `for codeUnit in s.utf16`

You can tidy things up and test for whether or not each individual `unichar` value is in a character set like this:

```
let char: Character = "\u{63}\u{20dd}" // This is a 'c' inside of an enclosing circle
for codeUnit in String(char).utf16 {
    if NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "c").characterIsMember(codeUnit) {
        dude.abide()
    } // dude will abide() for codeUnits[0] = "c", but not for codeUnits[1] = 0x20dd (the enclosing circle)
}
```

Or, if you are only interested in the first (and often only) `unichar` value:

```
if NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "c").characterIsMember(String(char).utf16[0]) {
    dude.abide()
}
```

Or, wrap it in a function:

```
func isChar(char: Character, inSet set: NSCharacterSet) -> Bool {
    return set.characterIsMember(String(char).utf16[0])
}

let xSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "x")
isChar("x", inSet: xSet)  // This returns true
isChar("y", inSet: xSet)  // This returns false
```

Now make the function check for *all* `unichar` values in a composed character - that way, if you have a composed character, the function will only return true if both the base character and the combining character are present:

```
func isChar(char: Character, inSet set: NSCharacterSet) -> Bool {
    var found = true
    for ch in String(char).utf16 {
        if !set.characterIsMember(ch) { found = false }
    }
    return found
}

let acuteA: Character = "\u{e1}"                   // An "a" with an accent
let acuteAComposed: Character = "\u{61}\u{301}"    // Also an "a" with an accent

// A character set that includes both the composed and uncomposed unichar values
let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "\u{61}\u{301}\u{e1}")

isChar(acuteA, inSet: charSet)           // returns true
isChar(acuteAComposed, inSet: charSet)   // returns true (both unichar values were matched
```

The last version is important. If your `Character` is a composed character you have to check for the presence of both the base character ("a") and the combining character (the acute accent) in the character set or you will get false positives.

Comment: This is very interesting. It doesn't solve my problem exactly, so I can't mark it as the answer, but it does explain why there's no direct `Character` -> `unichar`.

Comment: I refined my answer a bit. Beware that matt's answer, while a great way to check for non-composed characters, may not work for composed characters.

Comment: I am still digesting this. Fascinating.

Comment: I went down the rabbit-hole on this a few days ago and I haven't come back out yet :)

Comment: Shorter: `let units = [unichar](String(char).utf16)`

Comment: dude.abide()! love it.

Comment: Subscripting `UTF16View` is no longer supported. Instead use the index: `let utf16View = String(char).utf16; set.characterIsMember(utf16View[utf16View.startIndex])` It might be possible to do it shorter.

Answer (score 12):

I would treat the Character as a String and let Cocoa do all the work:

```
func charset(cset:NSCharacterSet, containsCharacter c:Character) -> Bool {
    let s = String(c)
    let ix = s.startIndex
    let ix2 = s.endIndex
    let result = s.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(cset, options: nil, range: ix..<ix2)
    return result != nil
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
let cset = NSCharacterSet.lowercaseLetterCharacterSet()
let c : Character = "c"
let ok = charset(cset, containsCharacter:c) // true
```

Comment: As I suspected. Basically, you have to turn `Character` into `String` in order to do this.

Comment: I've shamelessly stolen your code and turned it into an extension method on `NSCharacterSet`.

Comment: This can be simplified to `let result = s.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(cset)` because "options:" and "range:" are (now?) *optional* parameters.

Comment: @MartinR Agreed. I think what happened is that when I was working on that code, the shorter version didn't show up in Xcode's code completion (and still doesn't). - It isn't in the Swift version of the header, either. I wonder if this is a bug in the way Objective-C headers get turned into Swift.

Comment: @MartinR Same problem with e.g. `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` and `rangeOfString:options:`. These shorter versions don't show up in the Swift header or code completion. The workaround around is to cast the string to an NSString - then they show up. This implies that Swift cannot call the shorter versions, but it can. I have to regard this as a bug.

Comment: It seems that Xcode's autocompletion generally does not indicate optional parameters. `NSString` declares three *different* methods, that's why you see them separately in the autocompletion.

Comment: @MartinR these are Objective-C methods from the NSString API. There is no such thing as an optional parameter in Objective-C. It's Swift that has _created_ the idea that these parameters are optional (I see the `= default` in the header). But then I still regard the code completion behavior as a bug.

Comment: Shouldn't you also check that the returned range is from start to end, rather than just partial (as when just one of the scalars is inside the range)?

Answer (score 4):

Do it all in a one liner:

```
validCharacterSet.contains(String(char).unicodeScalars.first!)
```

(Swift 3)

Answer (score 3):

Due to changes in Swift 3.0, matt's answer no longer works, so here is working version (as extension):

```
private extension NSCharacterSet {

  func containsCharacter(c: Character) -> Bool {

       let s = String(c)
       let ix = s.startIndex
       let ix2 = s.endIndex
       let result = s.rangeOfCharacter(from: self as CharacterSet, options: [], range: ix..<ix2)
       return result != nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 changes means you actually don't need to be bridging to `NSCharacterSet` anymore, you can use Swift's native `CharacterSet`.

You could do something similar to Jiri's answer directly:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    func contains(_ character: Character) -> Bool {
        let string = String(character)
        return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: self, options: [], range: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex) != nil
    }
}
```

or do:

```
func contains(_ character: Character) -> Bool {
    let otherSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: String(character))
    return self.isSuperset(of: otherSet)
}
```

Note: the above crashes and doesn't work due to https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3667. Not sure `CharacterSet` gets the kind of love it needs.